# Which method requires fewer resources?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi Which of the following piece of code need or uses fewer resources?
Is there a better method? for writing in file ?

```
f=open("Contact.txt","r+")
    for i,j in enumerate(f):
        text=str(f.readline())
        if  text=="":
            f.write('\n'+ name +" "+ family+" " + MPN +" "+ Add + "*")
```

OR

```
f=open("Contact.txt","r+")
text=str(f.read())
f.write('\n'+ name +" "+ family+" " + MPN +" "+ Add + "*")
```

Comment: I suggest that you use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) for string concatenation.

Comment: `j` will already contain each line of `f` in succession. There is no need to call `f.readline()` in the body of the loop. If you do, `text` only gets every other line; `j` has the other ones.

Comment: Are you trying to write some data to empty lines in the file?

Comment: So you want to *append* to the end of the file? Then open the file in `"a"` mode.

Answer (score 2):

The first method is a bit wrong, when you iterate over the file (even using enumerate) it already reads the line and you get it in `j` , you do not need to do `f.readline()` again , that causes your code to skip alternate lines (Unless you really do want to skip alternate lines).

Also, both method do not perform same thing, the first one reads the file line by line, and the second one reads it completely and writes a newline at end.

Given that is fixed, first method takes fewer resources, since you do not read the complete file into memory, instead just read each line into memory and then write to the other file.

Another improvement I can suggest is to use `with` statement to correctly handle closing of files. Example -

```
with open("Contact.txt","r+") as f:
    for i,text in enumerate(f):
        if  text=="":
            f.write('\n'+ name +" "+ family+" " + MPN +" "+ Add + "*")
```

Answer (score 2):

i use this:

```
f = open("Contact.txt","a")
f.write('\n'+ name +" "+ family+" " + MPN +" "+ Add + "*")
```

Comment: Perhaps you mean `open("Contact.txt","a")`?

Comment: you should use `with`-statement to close the file and you could [use `print()` instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31905205/4279).

Answer (score 2):

If your intent is to add the contact at the end of the file:

```
with open("Contact.txt", "a") as file:
    print(name, family, MPN, Add + "*", file=file)
```

`print()` function insert spaces and the newline at the end of the line automatically.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only trying to add a line to the end of the file, the most efficient is

```
with open("Contact.txt", "a") as f:
    print("{} {} {} {} *".format(name, family, MPN, Add, file=f)
```

Opening the file in append mode automatically starts the file point at the end of the file, without needing to explicitly read through the file to start. The `format` method creates a single string, without all the intermediate strings created by chained addition.

Comment: it's just a simple Practice for writing in file. I'm looking for the most optimal way